# Not highlighting nodes after customize icons in JTree

Tags: java, swing, icons, nodes, jtree

I wanted to change node icons of a `JTree`, so I did this:

```
public class MyTreeCellRenderer implements TreeCellRenderer {
    private JLabel label;

    MyTreeCellRenderer() {
        label = new JLabel();
    }

    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded,
                                                  boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
        Object o = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode) value).getUserObject();
        if (o instanceof Node) {
            Node country = (Node) o;
            if (country.getImg() != null) {
                BufferedImage img = resizeImage(country.getImg()); // gives me an iconDimensions image
                label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
            }
            else {
                label.setIcon(null);
            }
        }
        return label;
    }
```

Righ after adding the renderer, to the tree by:

```
jTree.setCellRenderer(new MyTreeCellRenderer());
```

I got every node icon changed by its own image, I mean, it worked out.

But now, when I click on any of the tree nodes, these don't get highlighted. I don't understand why, I've never changed `jTree selectedModel`.

If I don't set `MyTreeCellRenderer` to the tree, it works perfectly, but once I added, the icons change, but its selected highlighting is gone.

Comment: Wait -- didn't I just see this *exact* same question about 1 or 2 hours ago?

Comment: [Indeed, I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56510462/how-to-set-highlighting-selected-node-of-jtree-after-icons-customized)

Comment: im sorry, i deleted it

Comment: If you’re not extending [DefaultTreeCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellRenderer.html), you should be.  And your method should be calling super.getTreeCellRendererComponent first, then calling `this.setIcon`.  DefaultTreeCellRenderer will take the `selected` argument into account.  Your code does not.

Comment: @VGR i already extended from DefaultTreeCellRenderer, and added this line to the method:
DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = (DefaultTreeCellRenderer)super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree,value,selected,expanded,leaf,row,hasFocus);

but i dont understand the this.setIcon part, how should i use it?

Comment: Do not create your own JLabel.  DefaultTreeCellRenderer extends JLabel, so call `this.setIcon` or `renderer.setIcon` instead of label.setIcon.

Comment: @VGR thanks a lot, its lighting it, do you know any way to light icon too?

Comment: Using an image editor to make the icon’s background transparent may help.  If you want a physically different icon, you’ll have to make it yourself, and add logic based on the value of the `selected` argument.